# How to loop through list of cities to calculate distances between them

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I'm working on a brain teaser where I want to calculate all of the possible distances between 4 cities. I wrote a function where you can input the x and y coordinates of the two cities and it'll calculate the distance between them.

While I can individually call the function 6 times,
that seems inefficient if the data set gets bigger. I think I should be using nested "for loops" but I can't figure out a way to properly increment the inner loop.

My initial idea was to create a list of object and use that in inner loop.

```html
import math #Imports the math module

def calc_euclidean(x1,y1,x2,y2): #Function takes 4 arguments
    xDistancesqrd=math.pow((x2-x1),2) #x2-x1 squared
    yDistancesqrd=math.pow((y2-y1),2) #y2-y1 squared
    euclideanDistance=math.sqrt(xDistancesqrd+yDistancesqrd) #distance=square root (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2
    return euclideanDistance #Returns the result of the calculation, the euclidean distance between the points.

Budapest=[47.4979, 19.0402]
Vienna=[48.210033, 16.363449]
Sofia=[42.6977, 23.3219]
Zagreb=[45.8150, 15.9819]

cities=[Budapest,Vienna,Sofia,Zagreb]
```

Comment: You can do calculations on sphere angles (degrees) simply by applying the Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: @KlausD. That's what the OP seems to be doing.

Comment: @Selcuk My autocorrect hit me harder than usual: You **can't** do...

Comment: @KlausD. It is ironic that it was Pythagoras who first proposed a spherical Earth too. That being said, Pythagoras theorem is a good approximation for cities in Europe, as they are very close to each other when compared to the size of the Earth therefore can be assumed that they are on a plane.

Comment: Please do not significantly edit the question after it has been answered.  If you have a new question, then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) like:

#### Code:

```
for c1, c2 in it.combinations(cities, 2):
    print(c1, c2, calc_euclidean(c1[0], c1[1], c2[0], c2[1]))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import math  # Imports the math module
import itertools as it


def calc_euclidean(x1, y1, x2, y2):  # Function takes 4 arguments
    xDistancesqrd = math.pow((x2 - x1), 2)  # x2-x1 squared
    yDistancesqrd = math.pow((y2 - y1), 2)  # y2-y1 squared
    euclideanDistance = math.sqrt(
        xDistancesqrd + yDistancesqrd)  # distance=square root (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2
    return euclideanDistance  # Returns the result of the calculation, the euclidean distance between the points.


Budapest = [47.4979, 19.0402]
Vienna = [48.210033, 16.363449]
Sofia = [42.6977, 23.3219]
Zagreb = [45.8150, 15.9819]

cities = [Budapest, Vienna, Sofia, Zagreb]
for c1, c2 in it.combinations(cities, 2):
    print(c1, c2, calc_euclidean(c1[0], c1[1], c2[0], c2[1]))
```

#### Results:

```
[47.4979, 19.0402] [48.210033, 16.363449] 2.769860885620431
[47.4979, 19.0402] [42.6977, 23.3219] 6.432330443159777
[47.4979, 19.0402] [45.815, 15.9819] 3.4907522541710128
[48.210033, 16.363449] [42.6977, 23.3219] 8.877266213327731
[48.210033, 16.363449] [45.815, 15.9819] 2.4252345681376934
[42.6977, 23.3219] [45.815, 15.9819] 7.974531916670721
```